# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value that is not equal to the supplied origin error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8080/*' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

I have create Middleware and nothing changed:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:8080/*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST,PUT,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Accept,Authorization,Content-Type')
        ->header('Content-Type','application/json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure But maybe chorme does not support `localhost`

Try wildcard `*` Instead of `http://localhost:8080/*`

Comment: I changed * Instead of http://localhost:8080/* and get this error:    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://blog.test/api/user' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: your allow credentials is `true` now to solve this `false` you allowcredetials in frontend

Comment: because you are testing it on localhost if it was hosted on a domain you will not get this error... whenever you using `*` off you allowcredentials