# CORS blocked origin - Origin and allowed origin are the same

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, google-chrome

Using dockerized Ory Kratos and Angular (www folder hosted via nginx to be able to modify headers) on localhost and trying to execute

```
const headers = {
   Accept: 'application/json',
};
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4433/self-service/registration/browser', {
  method: 'GET', 
  headers,
  redirect: 'follow',
  credentials: 'include',
})
.then((r) => console.log(r))
.catch((f) => console.log(f));
```

leads to

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8100/auth/register?flow=b35c3f9a-5592-4121-80b9-87503c38e1d3' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:4433/self-service/registration/browser') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://127.0.0.1:8100' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

http://127.0.0.1:4433/self-service/registration/browser redirects to [http://127.0.0.1:8100/custompath/register?flow=[some-flow-id]](http://127.0.0.1:8100/custompath/register?flow=%5Bsome-flow-id%5D) via a 302 HTTP response. The browser tries to resolve the redirect and throws the error mentioned above.

**Origin and allowed origin are the same** - so how can that error happen? I already found this answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62320912/14345380 if that's helpful.

Chrome version 87.0.4280.88

**Edit #1**
Network tab output can be seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWZ4.png)

**Edit #2**
To be able to resolve the issue yourself I set up a little repository: Find it [here](https://github.com/TMInnovations/testorykratos)

**Edit #3**
Thanks for the hint from [pandamakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6059235/pandamakes). The test repo is not running on :8100 but on 4200 (Switched from ionic project to angular project).

**Edit #4**
I started another discussion at the ory/kratos project origin [here](https://github.com/ory/kratos/discussions/915). The Ory Team implemented a SDK which we can use instead of plain fetch requests.

Comment: But it is redirected via :4433

Comment: I already tried to allow :4433, then both (:8100 and :4433), which is not supported.

Comment: does `http://127.0.0.1:8100` return the correct cors header? (show dev tool output if possible?)

Comment: Adapted the question to your needs.

Comment: and the web frontend is hosted on `127.0.0.1:8100` ?

Comment: I will also need to double check, but request `origin: null` looks sus. I will have to take a deeper look

Comment: The frontend is hosted via an nginx docker container on 127.0.0.1:8100. origin: null may be because of the redirection?

Comment: if the port is not the same, then i believe that CORS triggers... in other words : `different port = different origin`, even though host are same.

Comment: But even the ports are the same as it can be seen in the error message above. Also https://sequoia.makes.software/session-management-with-microservices/#i-thought-cookies-couldn-39-t-be-shared- suggests that different ports do not trigger CORS.

Comment: I cloned the repo, but couldn't find a reference to port 8100. I see nginx is listening on 4200 and kratos running on 4433? (edit: judging from `docker-compose.yml` alone)

Comment: it may be possible that CORS request cannot be redirected to a different host: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSExternalRedirectNotAllowed

Comment: Sorry therefore. I had the original repo running with ionic which is served at 8100. Angular is served on 4200. shouldn't make a big difference though. In the browser you can (like you already figured out by reading the docker-compose file) find it here: http://localhost:4200

Comment: I updated my question the 4th time => I think the SDK intends to be able to achieve it - so I really hope it's possible.

Comment: @tmi I understand what you are saying re: ports. I am trying something, but in the mean time, if you have time, as crazy as it sounds, try to remove https://github.com/TMInnovations/testorykratos/blob/main/docker/default.conf#L12 (yes, remove the cors header) and let me know how it goes?

Comment: I only use a reverse proxy to add this header. Without it the error is: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4200/?flow=031ec155-a18d-4719-a1b4-1cc78f9cba63' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4433/self-service/registration/browser') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: With '*' it's not throwing an error :-O But it's also not delivering the csrf_token cookie.

Comment: I just took a look at https://www.ory.sh/kratos/docs/reference/api/#initialize-registration-flow-for-browsers , I wonder if this endpoint is meant for your application hyper link to the url, rather than use fetch?

Comment: As my application should be a SPA I don't really want to reload the page. Currently I'm using (in my project and the min repo) the SDK provded by ory/kratos (which most probably also uses fetch).

Comment: do you have a repo for ory/drato sdk? or just use the sdk? SPA is not my forte. I typically use passportjs or openid for user auth

Comment: I'm not a developer of ory (unfortunately :-P). The sdk can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@oryd/kratos-client. And the sdk is generated automatically as you can read here: https://github.com/ory/kratos/blob/8e7f9f5ec3ac6f5675584974e8d189247b539634/docs/docs/sdk.md

Answer (score 0):

One thing is simply add no-cors to the request.

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

Also, you say you have Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set did you also set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` , since you are fetching with `credentials: "include"`.

Lastly setting credentials: "include" origin can not be a localhost or 127.0.0.1 or it will return false and cause a cors error, so either, set credentials to same-site or omit or get yourself a domain name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. no-cors will deliver an opaque response, which is not satisfying for a registration request that should respond with the flowid (look at rest-api doc here: https://www.ory.sh/kratos/docs/reference/api#initialize-registration-flow-for-browsers).

Tried to add the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true header but that dindn't have any effect.

Setting the credentials to same-origin has no effect. Same error message, same for omit.

So I think it's not related to the credentials header. Same happens if the credentials header is not adjusted in the header block.

Comment: I already have a domain. But I want myself and other contributing developers to be able to work on localhost. If there's no other solution, we maybe will switch to online development (not very cool).

Answer (score 0):

I ... think I got it...

The 302 redirection works, but when the fetch requests follows the redirection, it now attempts at fetching a non-cors resource. In this event, it will not attach an `Origin` request header (since it is a non CORS request).

When the response arrives, the browser will compare `access-control-allow-origin` header, if any exist, to the origin of the request. If the response header exists, and is **not** *, it **must** match the `origin` header of the request.

So solve your issue, you will want to remove the `access-control-allow-origin` in your nginx setup, or set it to `*`

min repro: https://github.com/xgui3783/cors-min-repro

Comment: Thank you! Omiting it in tmy repo did not work but setting it to * allowed it to not throw an error. However the csrf_token cookie is not delivered when doing so. Also the flow_id cannot be grabbed from the response as I see. In your repo I don't see cookies set. So: Yes it's working, but I can't clarify it with cookies (which are needed for the registration process at ory/kratos).